# network errors in windows

Tags: windows, networking, python, windows-error-reporting

i am desperately trying to fix this for weeks,  when doing anything that requires internet with anaconda on windows it gives this error:

```
Retrieving notices: ...working... Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen', None, 10054, None)': /pkgs/r/notices.json

Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen', None, 10054, None)': /pkgs/main/notices.json

Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen', None, 10054, None)': /pkgs/msys2/notices.json

Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen', None, 10054, None)': /pkgs/main/notices.json

Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen', None, 10054, None)': /pkgs/r/notices.json

Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen', None, 10054, None)': /pkgs/msys2/notices.json

Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen', None, 10054, None)': /pkgs/msys2/notices.json

Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen', None, 10054, None)': /pkgs/r/notices.json

Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen', None, 10054, None)': /pkgs/main/notices.json

ERROR conda.notices.fetch:get_channel_notice_response(68): Request error <HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.anaconda.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/msys2/notices.json (Caused by ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen', None, 10054, None)))> for channel: defaults url: https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/notices.json
ERROR conda.notices.fetch:get_channel_notice_response(68): Request error <HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.anaconda.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/main/notices.json (Caused by ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen', None, 10054, None)))> for channel: defaults url: https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/notices.json
ERROR conda.notices.fetch:get_channel_notice_response(68): Request error <HTTPSConnectionPool(host='repo.anaconda.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /pkgs/r/notices.json (Caused by ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen', None, 10054, None)))> for channel: defaults url: https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/notices.json
done
Channels:
 - defaults
Platform: win-64
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): - Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen', None, 10054, None)': /pkgs/msys2/noarch/repodata.json.zst

Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen', None, 10054, None)': /pkgs/r/win-64/repodata.json.zst

\ Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen', None, 10054, None)': /pkgs/msys2/win-64/repodata.json.zst

| Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen', None, 10054, None)': /pkgs/r/noarch/repodata.json.zst

Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen', None, 10054, None)': /pkgs/main/noarch/repodata.json.zst

Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen', None, 10054, None)': /pkgs/main/win-64/repodata.json.zst

/ Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen', None, 10054, None)': /pkgs/msys2/noarch/repodata.json.zst

- Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen', None, 10054, None)': /pkgs/r/win-64/repodata.json.zst

\ Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen', None, 10054, None)': /pkgs/msys2/win-64/repodata.json.zst

| Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen', None, 10054, None)': /pkgs/r/noarch/repodata.json.zst

Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen', None, 10054, None)': /pkgs/main/noarch/repodata.json.zst

Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen', None, 10054, None)': /pkgs/main/win-64/repodata.json.zst

\ Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen', None, 10054, None)': /pkgs/msys2/noarch/repodata.json.zst

/ Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen', None, 10054, None)': /pkgs/r/win-64/repodata.json.zst

\ Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen', None, 10054, None)': /pkgs/msys2/win-64/repodata.json.zst

Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen', None, 10054, None)': /pkgs/main/win-64/repodata.json.zst

Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen', None, 10054, None)': /pkgs/r/noarch/repodata.json.zst

Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen', None, 10054, None)': /pkgs/main/noarch/repodata.json.zst

failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url <https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64/repodata.json>
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.

If your current network has https://repo.anaconda.com blocked, please file
a support request with your network engineering team.

'https//repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64'
```

sorry for the long error message but i had to show it.
i have tried:

reinstalling anaconda

checking my wifi

disabling any firewall of antivirus

copying libcrypto and libssl dll files to DLLS folder

installing latest openssl.

running sfc /scannow in cmd prompt.

i also use no proxy /vpn/company network and the worst part is that this issue is not even conda related because i have connection issues in other programs too like firefox which gives pr_connect_reset error. Please give any answer.

Edit: i looked up many instances of this problem on github and stackoverflow but none of the methods helped, also i am using wsl 2 and windows 10 but i am not sure what wsl has to do with this.